# How will Android select the correct resource given the pixel density and API version of the running device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-theme, android-styles

I am studying Android examples and I am quite confused by the structure inside the *res* folder.

```
res
├───drawable-hdpi
│       ic_action_search.png
│       ic_launcher.png
│
├───drawable-ldpi
│       ic_launcher.png
│
├───drawable-mdpi
│       ic_action_search.png
│       ic_launcher.png
│
├───drawable-xhdpi
│       ic_action_search.png
│       ic_launcher.png
│
├───layout
│       activity_main.xml
│       activity_result.xml
│
├───menu
│       activity_main.xml
│       activity_main_activity2.xml
│       activity_result.xml
│
├───values
│       dimens.xml
│       strings.xml
│       styles.xml
│
├───values-large
│       dimens.xml
│
├───values-v11
│       styles.xml
│
└───values-v14
        styles.xml
```

I have four questions:

**1** - When will Android know when to use *hdpi*, *ldpi*, ... variations of the image resources?

**2** - When will Android know when to use *values* or any of the *values-vAPI_VERSION*? If I have API 13 will it use *values-v11* or *values-v14*?

**3** - When will Android use the resources in the *values* folder? When he will not? If I have, for example, API 14, will he use all the files in the *values* folder except for the *styles.xml*, which will be overriden by the *styles.xml* file from values-v14?

**4** - Can I also have folders such as *menu-v11*, *menu-ldpi*, *layout-ldpi* or *layout-v14*?

I have read the documentation from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html), but they don't answer most of these questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Android knows it by querying your device. It will automatically get **1**, the density; **2** the API Level. **3** Your themes and styles override the system ones. **4**: yes - at least, I experimented with `layout-port` and `layout-land`

Comment: If the phone has API 13 will it use values-v11 or values-v14?

Comment: **11**. Since it will use the equal `or lower`. `values-11` says "from 11 on" (until a bigger `matching` values folder is found).

Comment: @DerGolem don't you want to sum this up into a proper answer so that I can mark this question as answered, hence giving you the deserved reputation points?

Comment: Just done. You're now free to remove the post from the Unanswered Questions Queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android knows it by querying your device.

It will automatically get:

- **1**, the density;
- **2** the API Level.

**3** Your themes and styles override the system ones.
**4** Yes - at least, I experimented with `layout-port` and `layout-land`

If the current device has got an API Level of **13**, then the `values-v11` folder will be choosen.

This is because it will match the `lower` API Level.
`values-11` says: "from 11 on" (until a bigger matching values folder is found).